# Hitting exception when using Google Protobuf Any UnpackTo function in C++

Tags: protocol-buffers

```
google::protobuf::Any anyResponse = someResponse.response();
ResponseType unpackResp; //ResponseType is a subclass of google::protobuf::Message
if (anyResponse.UnpackTo(&unpackResp))
{
    ...
}
```

Running this piece of C++ code and access vialotion exception happens in `anyResponse.UnpackTo(&unpackResp)`. Does someone know how to debug into this function? I checked anyResponse and it looks good.
It went through these files in google::protobuf:
[call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJQ5A.png)

Anyway I can see these files?